# public final By xxx all over the place

Tags: java

For my Cucumber/Selenium project I'm using a Page Object Model. There is HomePage, SettingsPage, SearchWidget, etc. Classes look like this:

```java
public class SearchWidget extends Page {
  public final By buttonDisplayTypeLoc = By.id("button-displayType");
  public final By buttonResultsPerPageLoc = By.id("button-resultsPerPage");
  // lots more of the same
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to keep track of locators (the By's), instead of having long lists of them at the beginning of each Page subclass?

I've tried a separate class Element that holds a Map of a String key and a By locator. The Map could be easily added to and retrieved from. The problem with that, is that using `Element.getLocator("key");` doesn't get the IDE's help with spelling for the key anymore. So I scratched that.

There's already a Site class that holds things like URL's, etc. I could easily put it there, and although it does pertain to the site, it doesn't sit well with me to have a whole bunch of fields that I'd rather have in the class it pertains to. Although it would be kind of out of sight ...

I looked at using a factory model, but it seems like overkill.

So, again, is there a more elegant way to do this, or should I just leave it alone? They are defined in the class they belong to, and although it does look ugly, it's also easy to maintain.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You are correct, of course. I was hoping for something more neat, and that isn't the purpose. Wish I could accept your answer as Answered.

Comment: There you go :-)

Comment: If your IDE supports it, one thing you could do to help with the ugliness is to add Code Folding blocks around all of these definition.  Then you could at least hide them while you're working on the code by collapsing that block.  I do a lot with Folding in IntelliJ.  I don't know about other IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Page Object Model design pattern](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/guidelines_and_recommendations/page_object_models/) is designed to keep everything related to the "page" in one place. Moving these around to different classes just for house keeping sort of breaks that model as described here from the link: "Subsequently all changes to support that new UI are located in one place."